# Cannot find the method on the object instance. when debugging Blend

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, expression-blend

I am attaching My VS2010 to Blend in order to debug design time error, but I got to a point where I am getting an error that says "Cannot find the method on the object instance" this looks like a zombie object it's Alive but you cannot see any property or collection from it so when blend try to bind to this collection VS throws the "Cannot find the method on the object instance"